# how to give yes as default option to apt-get install in ubuntu

Tags: linux

I want to create a script so that I can download and install multiple linux software or packages. When some one download any package using apt-get install command, it asks to enter yes/no to proceed further. I want to pass yes in script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>   Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs then apt-get will abort.
>   Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

[image: Be like Bill]

Comment: Thanks but now I can not give you any point because I'm not eligible.

Comment: I like Bill....